# Efficient Data Transfer from Excel VBA to Web-Service

Tags: vba, excel, large-data

I have a large worksheet (~250K rows, 22 columns, ~40MB plain data) which has to transfer its content to an intranet API. Format does not matter. The problem is: When accessing the data like

```
Const ROWS = 250000
Const COLS = 22

Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim myRange As Variant
Dim dummyString As String
Dim sb As New cStringBuilder

myRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(ROWS, COLS)).Value2

For x = 1 To ROWS
    For y = 1 To COLS
        dummyString = myRange(x, y) 'Runtime with only this line: 1.8s
        sb.Append dummyString 'Runtime with this additional line 163s
    Next
Next
```

I get a wonderful 2D array, but I am not able to collect the data efficiently for HTTP export.
An X/Y loop over the array and access `myRange[x, y]` has runtimes >1min. I was not able to find an array method which helps to get the imploded/encoded content of the 2D array.
My current workaround is missusing the clipboard ([Workaround for Memory Leak when using large string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52390267/workaround-for-memory-leak-when-using-large-string)) which works fast, but is a dirty workaround in my eyes AND has one major problem: The values I get are formatted, “.Value” and not “.Value2”, so I have to convert the data on server site again before usage, e.g. unformat currency cells to floats.

What could be another idea to deal with the data array?

Comment: What type of object is `myRange`? I suspect you declared it as `Range` object and not an actual variant. If you declare as variant, looping through it will be MUCH faster. [See example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba)

Comment: Please show your existing loop code.  There are VBA implmentations of a "stringbuilder"  class which likely is what you want here.  Also "250M" rows - do you mean 250k?

Comment: Scott: Yes it is a variant, the `set` was copied by mistake. Tim: 250K, not 250M, thanks. I updated the question with the complete test function

Comment: You might want to replace `Dim sb As New cStringBuilder` with `Dim sb As cStringBuilder: Set sb = new cstringbuilder`. So the object's instance doesn't need to be checked each time you refer to it.

Comment: I presume your stringbuilder class/object is using some form of `join` to reduce overhead of concatenating immutable strings -- and is therefore reasonably efficient.

Comment: @chillin: The Stringbuilder class is one of the VBA implementations I found which makes use of the Windows CopyMemory API (http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Techniques/StringBuilder/String_Builder_Class_and_Demonstration_zip_cStringBuilder_cls.html) I changed the `Dim` line, but It makes no difference.

Comment: A direct API call of CopyMemor to get the whole Array structure to a string/byte buffer could be a possibility, but I'm new to that topic (array pointers, size of memory block etc., hard to start...).

Comment: Sorry if I'm covering old ground/stuff you've already tried, but how long does it take with simple `cstr` and `join`?

Comment: Can you provide more Details of your thoughts? join does not work with 2D Arrays, afaik. Or do you mean collecting all values into a 1D Array an then join to a String?

Comment: Yes, my thoughts are that you create two string arrays `A` and `B`. `A` can be of size `1 to ROWS`, `B` can be of size of `1 to COLUMNS`. As you loop over each row in your `myRange` array, fill each element in `B` with each column's value in that row. After the final column for that row and before you move to the next row, join array `B` and assign to the row in `A`. With a loop of this size, only put necessary stuff inside the loop itself. At the end you would join `A`. You might need to use `cstr` when assigning items to `B`. would write an answer, but my comment is experimental.

Comment: @chillin, please post this as an answer so I can give you the points. I tried and it works perfect, my plain runtime collecting the data is ~ 3.5s
Is seems the "two-level-join-contruct" is much more efficient than the other ways

Comment: @Matschek Sure, I have posted this as an answer, as well as some code in case it benefits anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thoughts are that you create two string arrays `A` and `B`. `A` can be of size `1 to ROWS`, `B` can be of size of `1 to COLUMNS`. As you loop over each row in your `myRange` array, fill each element in `B` with each column's value in that row. After the final column for that row and before you move to the next row, join array `B` and assign to the row in `A`. With a loop of this size, only put necessary stuff inside the loop itself. At the end you would join `A`. You might need to use `cstr()` when assigning items to `B`.

Matschek (OP) was able to write the code based on the above, but for anyone else's benefit, the code itself might be something like:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub concatenateArrayValues()

    Const TOTAL_ROWS As Long = 250000
    Const TOTAL_COLUMNS As Long = 22

    Dim inputValues As Variant
    inputValues = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(TOTAL_ROWS, TOTAL_COLUMNS).Value2

    ' These are static string arrays, as OP's use case involved constants.
    Dim outputArray(1 To TOTAL_ROWS) As String ' <- in other words, array A
    Dim interimArray(1 To TOTAL_COLUMNS) As String ' <- in other words, array B

    Dim rowIndex As Long
    Dim columnIndex As Long

    ' We use constants below when specifying the loop's limits instead of Lbound() and Ubound()
    ' as OP's use case involved constants.
    ' If we were using dynamic arrays, we could call Ubound(inputValues,2) once outside of the loop
    ' And assign the result to a Long type variable
    ' To avoid calling Ubound() 250k times within the loop itself.

    For rowIndex = 1 To TOTAL_ROWS
        For columnIndex = 1 To TOTAL_COLUMNS
            interimArray(columnIndex) = inputValues(rowIndex, columnIndex)
        Next columnIndex
        outputArray(rowIndex) = VBA.Strings.Join(interimArray, ",")
    Next rowIndex

    Dim concatenatedOutput As String
    concatenatedOutput = VBA.Strings.Join(outputArray, vbNewLine)

    Debug.Print concatenatedOutput

    ' My current machine isn't particularly great
    ' but the code above ran and concatenated values in range A1:V250000
    ' (with each cell containing a random 3-character string) in under 4 seconds.

End Sub
```